# Fade in effect from top to a paragraph?

Tags: html, css, animation

Does anyone now a css3 way to fade in text from top, more precise to show text line by line with fade and some delay between them. I tried animating the opacity, positions, line-heights and so on but i didn't find the right combination. And my main problem is that i have a complicated background on my main content.

Answer (score 2):

The line by line part can probably only be solved by setting the right keyframes and then calling the animation.

I could image solving this be setting a container `div` to `overflow: hidden` and then animating the `height` of the container step by step with several keyframes.

More on this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: I forgot to add overflow:hidden. Thx for the heads-up.